# Hide <p> element if innerHTML is "0" or empty

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple calculator but I am stuck; I need to hide some elements. My code is shown with comments below.

```js
function ekogroszek() {
  var p = document.getElementById("powierzchnia").value;
  var w = document.getElementById("wysokosc").value;
  var k = p * w;
  var e = 7.8;
  var s = k * e;
  document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML = s;
}


$('#wysokosc').keypress(function(event) {
  if (((event.which != 46 || (event.which == 46 && $(this).val() == '')) ||
      $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}).on('paste', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

$('#powierzchnia').keypress(function(event) {
  if (((event.which != 46 || (event.which == 46 && $(this).val() == '')) ||
      $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}).on('paste', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>First field</span>
  <input class="polekalkulacji" type="text" id="powierzchnia" name="powierzchnia" placeholder="np. 120">
</div>

<div>
  <span>Second</span>
  <input class="polekalkulacji" type="text" id="wysokosc" name="wysokosc" placeholder="np. 2.8">
</div>

<button onclick="ekogroszek()">Calculate</button>

<!--- Show below elements only if number (p id=wynik) is bigger than: "0" and field is filled --->
<p id="zapotrzebowanie">Result is:</p>
<p type="text" id="wynik"></p>
```

So as you can see I need to show these two "p" elements only if id=wynik is filled and bigger than 0. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why do you mix raw javascript with jQuery. If you're going to be using jQuery, you should just stick with the selectors, to save time/trouble. ie. `$('#powierzchnia').val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to keep them hidden until anything is written on them, and also the value on it is greater than 0, then the best way to achieve it is by hidding them on default with:

```
<p id="zapotrzebowanie" style="display: none;">Result is:</p>
<p type="text" id="wynik" style="display:none;"></p>
```

And when you are writting HTML to them, show them with jQuery:

```
function ekogroszek() {
  var p = $("#powierzchnia").val();
  var w = $("#wysokosc").val();
  var k = p * w;
  var e = 7.8;
  var s = k * e;
  document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML = Math.trunc(s);
  if(s>0){
    $("#zapotrzebowanie").show();
    $("#wynik").show();
  }
}
```

You can check a working version of your code in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0arcxze4/2/

Comment: I think this could work :) Thank you but it is possible to hide also decimal places in the result?

Comment: Of course, you just need to do `Math.trunc(s)`. I edited the code with it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply check to the value:

```
if($(this).val() == '0' || $(this).val() == '' ) {
  $('#wynik').hide();
}
```

You may show with jquery and at initial phase hide the html element with css. But I see you're showing them after calculating? Then, that's just fine.

But if you want the harder way then it is:

```
$('#wynik').css('display', function(i, v) {
  return ($(this).text() == '0' || $(this).text() == '') ? 'none' : 'block'
});
```